# Are the answers on this question worthy of a spam-flag?

Tags: discussion, spam

Doing a few low quality reviews, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26232830/916299).

It seems quite obvious to me that the authors of the the answers are affiliated with the product. The answers are reasonably low quality anyway, but are they worthy of a spam flag and the associated black mark against the accounts?

The description of the spam flag is:

> Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation.

This is where I have conflicting views. The answers don't **only** exist to promote; they are answers. However, they don't disclose affiliation either.

What is the best course of action in this case please?

---

The post has since been deleted, but here is the original question and the original revisions of the answers.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: "_Paychex API is live! Go to developer.paychex.com for more details on gaining access._" Even more spammy..

Comment: I don't disagree. However, "The API wasn't live" and "The API is now live" **are** answers.

Comment: Ah .. fortunately, this and the OP's other 2 questions (which, to me, look all the same) are off-topic. VTC and they will hopefully disappear.

Comment: If this is spam then it is certainly the most clumsy spam I've ever seen.  "We are working on it" and "It's done" just don't promote anything, it is one developer telling another what he's been working on.  The problem is with the question, not the answers.  It can be deleted, it is no longer relevant.

Comment: I love how already two users have chosen to interpret your question as rhetorical and spam-flagged the answers to the question.

Comment: @BoltClock, They are apparently more assertive than me. What is the moderator's point of view here?

Comment: @James Webster: Question is trash, in light of which answers are irrelevant.

Comment: Agree with flags: spam. These answers are not of general use to programmers, nor do they address a common programming problem. One was a solicitation for Twitter interaction, the other was a launch announcement better suited to a tweet and only relevant and factual ("is now live!") in that moment -- next year or even next month the statement will be useless. "Spam" is noise that does not serve the purposes of the place it is posted, it isn't always advertising.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam...."

One of the primary reasons this close vote option exists is because these questions attract spam. That this one got spam answers shouldn't be surprising, but asking for it doesn't make those answers not spam.

*"Hit us up on on Twitter"* and *"Go to [our site] for more details on gaining access"* aren't informative, they're promotional. And I don't believe the minimal "it doesn't exist yet" and "now it does" take the answers beyond

> Exist[ing] only to promote a product or service

Comment: It also diminishes Stack Overflow as a resource if an answer is allowed to point to off-site information without actually providing any of its own. External URLs should be treated as temporary, because they are.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, there's not even a link on the address given, and if there was a link it would be a link-only answer, so an incomplete answer at best.

All in all, the question itself is off-topic as recommending a tutorial/external documentation with no real programming problem exposed, it's unlikely to be of use to any future reader so should be closed and deleted, fixing the answers problem.

In a more general idea, answers which just point toward a site without giving an answer with quotes support from the site and/or examples tailored to the question should be deleted.

The spam flag is rarely the best one for the case I'm talking about, usually they are better targeted for a Not An Answer flag or Comment as Answer. In the case discussed, "Comment as Answer" seems the better fit, author affiliated with the product or not.

FWIW I just VTC the question, didn't flag the answers

Comment: `examples tailored to the question should be deleted`. But should they be flagged as spam? Writing *bad* answers doesn't necessarily mean that the author deserves the associated black mark that comes with a spam flag.

Comment: Your comment on the question just answered my comment on this answer. I've appended it.

Comment: @JamesWebster I've updated the answer with a more detailed expression of my point of view and kept your addition, thanks for the head up.